# Build all go packages in project

Tags: go, continuous-integration

I am making a Go project containing a few packages. Those are data structures (and there will be algorithms as well). My project root looks like this:

```
C:.
├───array
├───binary_tree
├───heap
└───list
```

The thing is, I want to add like a CI. So I would have a job checking if all packages build and if all tests pass.

Unfortunately, I can't run `go build` on project root. I have to pass whole path to it. I mean I could write a script which calls `go build X/Y/foo` and then `go build X/Y/bar`, but the CI on GitLab (docker image) won't have those paths, it will just `git clone` my repo and that's it (cuz I cannot run it on a relative path from project root, but a relative path from `GOPATH`, so like `github.com/dabljues/project_name/array`). And what about the test?

So the question there would be: Can I somehow run `go build` and `go test` for all the packages in the Go project? (located in separate folders)

Comment: `go test ./...` will test everything in or under the current directory.  See [Package lists and patterns](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns) in the `go` command documentation.

Comment: Wow, that is the thing I was looking for I guess. Make it an answer and I can accept it, @DavidMaze!

Comment: Btw I don't know why my question is getting so many downvotes

Answer (score -3):

Use a Makefile. Define the targets and instruction to compile them.

For example define the following in a Makefile

```
build:
    go build -o bin/main main.go

run:
    go run main.go
```

To run just invoke : `make build`

Comment: As I said - I can't, because i.e `go build ./array` doesn't work, cuz the paths is relative to project root. `go build github.com/dabljues/project_name/array` works, cuz it's the relative path to `$GOPATH/src` and I won't have it on docker container